# set min and max values for a field dynamically based on the value of drop down selected in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, validation, form-validation, angularjs

https://jsfiddle.net/05Ldg6uv/6/

I tried using angularJs referring the above link but the min and max fields did not get set in magento.

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'nickname', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'number',
    'label'         => 'Roll Number',
    'min'          => '{{min}}',
    'max'         => '{{max}}',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 1,
    'user_defined'  => 1,
    'admin_html'    => 1,
    'unique'        => 1, 
));
```